# Undamped Forces

Tags: dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems

I want to make sure I am doing this problem correctly, especially when it comes to drawing the potential function V(x).

Consider the system of differential equations:

$$\dot {x}=y$$
$$\dot {y}=-x+x^3$$

a. Find the fixed points

$\dot {x}=y$
$y=0$

$\dot {y}=-x+x^3$
$x=-1,1,0$

b. Find the potential function V(x) and draw its graph.  Classify the type of each fixed point.

$V(x)=-\int_{x_0}^x \! F(s) \, \mathrm{d}s$
$V(x)=-\int_{0}^x \! -s+s^3 \, \mathrm{d}s$

$V(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{4}$

Jacobian:

$DF_{(x,y)}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1+3x^2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

$DF_{(0,0)}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

$λ=±i$

(0,0) is a center.

$DF_{(±1,0)}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

$λ=±\sqrt {2}$

(±1,0) are saddle points.

$V(0)=0$ (local minimum) and $V(±1)=1/4$ (local maxima)

[image]
c. Draw the phase portrait for the system of differential equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given:

$$x'= y \\ y'=-x+x^3$$

This system has three critical points at:

$$(x, y) = (-1, 0), (0,0), (1, 0)$$

The Jacobian is given by:

$$J(x, y) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1+3x^2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Evaluating $J(x, y)$ at $(\pm~1, 0)$, we have eigenvalues:

$$\lambda_{1, 2} = \pm ~ \sqrt{2} \implies ~\mbox{saddle point}$$

Evaluating $J(x, y)$ at $(0, 0)$, we have eigenvalues:

$$\lambda_{1, 2} = \pm i \implies ~\mbox{center}$$

A phase portrait shows:

[image]

The potential function is given by:

$$V(x) = \displaystyle -\int_{x_0}^x F(s) ~ds = -\int_{0}^x (-s+s^3) ~ds = \dfrac{x^2}{2}-\dfrac{x^4}{4}$$

A plot of this shows:

[image]

I tried to line up the phase portrait and potential function. See what is going on there?